# SharePoint list created with number 1 for internal name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, custom-list, internal-name

I have created the SharePoint document library named as 'mydocument'. The display name of the library is same. But internal name is 'mydocument1'. I don't know how it's happening. Anyone suggest some idea why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a list, the name you enter becomes both the internal name (and url), and the display name. When you rename a list, only the display name is changed.

Here's the steps to show what's happening:

1. Create a new Custom list and name it "TestList".
2. Navigate to the list and note that the URL contains "TestList".
3. Go to the list and List Settings and use "List name, description and navigation" to rename it to something like "TestListNorth".
4. Note the URL. It's still "TestList".
5. Create a new Custom list and name it "TestList".
6. Navigate to the list and note that the URL contains "TestList1". This is also the internal name. The display name is "TestList".
7. Change the display name of this list to "TestListEast" and note that the URL is still "TestList1".
8. Create yet another new Custom list and name it "TestList".
9. Navigate to the list and note that the URL contains "TestList2". This is also the internal name. The display name is "TestList".
10. Change the display name of this list to "TestListWest" and note that the URL is still "TestList2".

The internal name is both unique and not changeable from the UI. The display name is also unique amongst the display names, but can be different than the internal name.

Comment: Thank you. But when I delete the site collection and recreated it, at the first time also the list created with '1'. Is any wrong direction.?

Comment: Site Collection deletion is a background process that takes time to run. When you created the new list, a list with the same name and URL (site collection path) was still in the SQL table, so they added a number to make it unique.  Is this an on-prem or SharePoint Online system? How are you creating your list? SharePoint page, PowerShell, workflow, code? In some cases we can force the cleanup.

Comment: I am using SharePoint on-prem . The list  was created through the code.

Comment: From the Central Admin Site Collection delete page: Important:  "This action will permanently delete all content and user information, but the hard disk space will not be immediately available. When you delete a large site, SharePoint removes data gradually for performance reasons. To perform an immediate deletion, you need to run a set of commands using, for example, Power Shell or the Object Model. Find more information, see the SharePoint Help system."

Comment: Also: "When a site collection (that is, a SPSite object) is accidentally deleted in SharePoint 2013, the deleted site collection is stored in the SPDeletedSite object, not the SPSite object. To restore a deleted site collection, you must use the Restore-SPDeletedSite Windows PowerShell cmdlet or programmatically access the object model."  (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272537.aspx)

Comment: So.. you could write code, or use PowerShell, to force "immediate deletion" of the Site Collection.  I.e. use "Remove-SPSite -Identity <URL>" and not "Remove-SPSite -Identity <URL> -GradualDelete", or the code equivalent.